# How to return a new ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

Which is populated from a text file, with five pieces of information per object.

One of the pieces of information is the "grade". I want to print all the students in a specific grade. My current method only shows the first instance of the student with in the grade. With "[]" around that one.

```
public ArrayList<Student> studentInGrade(String category) {
    ArrayList<Student> gradeCategory = new ArrayList<Student>();
    for (Student stu : studentList ) {
        if (stu.GetCategory().toUpperCase().contains(category.toUpperCase())) {
            System.out.println("Found");
            gradeCategory .add(stu );
            return gradeCategory ;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("No Category Found");
    return null;
}
```

Example:

I want to see all the students who are "junior".

Example Input:

```
Johnny Johns
Computer Science
Junior
21
In-State
Asheley Ashers
Nursing
Sophomore
20
In-State
Andrew Anders
Basket Weaving
Graduate Student
18
Out-State
Morgan Freeman
Theater
Junior
21
In-State
```

What I want to output:

```
Johnny Johns
Computer Science
Junior
21
In-State
Morgan Freeman
Theater
Junior
21
In-State
```

What outputs currently:

```
[Johnny Johns
Computer Science
Junior
21
In-State]
```

Comment: where are the variables `dvdEntry` and `catDVD` coming from? I also think your problem is you are returning a list while still in the loop, put the return statement outside the loop.

Comment: Oops, I changed my code a little so my actual code isn't all over the internet...

Comment: Maybe `return` outside the loop?

Comment: Please do not copy code without trying to understand it first.  You copied an example that dealt with renting DVDs and used it without changing the example to fit this problem.  Your code should not compile at all.  Now that you edited it, it might compile, but you're still using concepts from what you based your answer on.

Comment: @EricJablow , it's my original code that I am writing. I changed some stuff because I thought it'd also be easier to explain.

Comment: You still left the 'category' references in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you return, that breaks your for-loop.  In order to get all the students, you must iterate over the entire list and return your results afterwards.

Try putting it after the loop:

```
public ArrayList<Student> studentInGrade(String category) {
    ArrayList<Student> gradeCategory = new ArrayList<Student>();
    for (DVD stu : studentList ) {
        if (stu.GetCategory().toUpperCase().contains(category.toUpperCase())) {
            System.out.println("Found");
            gradeCategory .add(dvdEntry);
        }
    }
    return gradeCategory;
}
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but wouldn't be better to return `gradeCategory ` instead of `catDVD`?

Comment: yup, sorry, I copied trama's code without looking.  Fixed it now

Comment: @dspyz , this definitely works and is a lot closer, but it still returns the "[]" at the beginning and end of the returning list. And there are now "," between each object. I checked my toString method in my other class, and I didn't put in a ",".

Comment: That's how `ArrayList.toString()` works.  You'll have to customize it yourself.

Comment: return is the last thing a method does.  When a method returns, it is no longer running and it only returns once.  I don't know what you mean by "it still returns the '[]' at the beginning and end of the returning list", but I can guarantee you this method returns a single ArrayList containing only the things whose GetCategory() methods contain the string category.  That will be an empty list if no such student exists

Comment: @dspyz , I have made my own toString method in another class. How do I use it? I am sorry for these "dumb" questions... I swear, I am trying my hardest.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have left out a lot of relevant code.  However, it seems the underlying problem is that you are returning as soon as you find one match, instead of collecting all matches.  Just move your return outside the loop:

```
ArrayList<Student> gradeCategory = new ArrayList<Student>();
for (DVD stu : studentList ) {
    if (stu.GetCategory().toUpperCase().contains(category.toUpperCase())) {
        System.out.println("Found");
        gradeCategory .add(dvdEntry);
    }
}

return catDVD;
```

Comment: I think you should be returning `gradeCategory` not `catDVD`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Only now that the code has been edited.  Before the code returned `catDVD`, the definition of which was not included.  The claim that the code was printing one record implied that the code did function with that return, as though `catDVD` in some way included `gradeCategory`.  My mention of "You seem to have left out a lot of relevant code" was referring to this.

Comment: I kinda questioned it before, but that's just me :P

Answer (score 1):

The `return` in the loop ends the method, use `break`, or `continue` in loops instead.

```
public ArrayList<Student> studentInGrade(String category) {
  ArrayList<Student> gradeCategory = new ArrayList<Student>();
  for (Student stu : studentList ) {
    if (stu.GetCategory().toUpperCase().contains(category.toUpperCase())) {
      System.out.println("Found");
      gradeCategory .add(stu );
    }
  }
  if (gradeCategory.size() > 0)
    return gradeCategory;
  else {
    System.out.println("No Category Found");
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 Interesting to see you try and maintain the original return result of `null` for an empty result. (Although, personally, I prefer an empty list, but that's me ;))

Comment: I tried '.length', but it didnt compile. .size() seemed to work better.

Comment: My bad, I am working on Python, JavaScript, and ActionScript at the moment. `len`, `length`, `length()`, `size()`,... They're all the same right?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl haha yeah basically. But I got the jist of what you were saying. I appreciate it.